# Nested multiparameter classes

Tags: haskell, types, nested, multiparameter

I am trying to define a new data type containing a data type with multiple parameters (phantom types) in Haskell:

```
newtype Dd x y z = ToDd Cudd.Cudd.DdNode deriving (Eq,Show)

data KnowStruct a b c =
  KnS Cudd.Cudd.DdManager [Prp] (Dd a b c) [(Agent,[Prp])]
  deriving (Eq,Show)
```

But this gives me the error message:

```
• Expected kind ‘k0 -> k1 -> *’, but ‘Dd a’ has kind ‘*’
• In the type ‘(Dd a b c)’
```

Why is this the case?

Is it also possible to define KnowStruct without using any requirement of context / parameter specification for the contained Dd type? e.g. :

```
data KnowStruct =
  KnS Cudd.Cudd.DdManager [Prp] (Dd a b c) [(Agent,[Prp])]
  deriving (Eq,Show)
```

I made a function class dealing with all variations of Dds, and only use these in the functions acting on KnowStructs - so in theory there is no need to specify what kind of Dd the KnowStruct contains..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one works for me, try giving them explicit kind signatures

```
{-# Language DerivingStrategies       #-}
{-# Language PolyKinds                #-}
{-# Language StandaloneKindSignatures #-}

import Data.Kind

data DdManager = DdManager deriving stock (Eq, Show)
data DdNode    = DdNode    deriving stock (Eq, Show)
data Agent     = Agent     deriving stock (Eq, Show)
data Prp       = Prp       deriving stock (Eq, Show)

type    Dd :: k -> j -> i -> Type
newtype Dd x y z = ToDd DdNode
  deriving stock (Eq, Show)

type KnowStruct :: k -> j -> i -> Type
data KnowStruct a b c =
  KnS DdManager [Prp] (Dd a b c) [(Agent,[Prp])]
  deriving stock (Eq, Show)
```

> Is it also possible to define `KnowStruct` without using any requirement of context / parameter specification for the contained Dd type?

This is possible, and is called existential quantification because the type variables don't appear in the return type.

Deriving `Show` requires standalone deriving because of the existential quantification and `Eq` can't be easily derived. Since `a`, `b`, `c` are existentially quantified when you are comparing two `KnowStruct`s you are comparing `Dd a1 b1 c1` and `Dd a2 b2 c2` with completely different type variables.

```
{-# Language ExistentialQuantification #-}
{-# Language StandaloneDeriving        #-}

import Data.Kind

data DdManager = DdManager deriving stock (Eq, Show)
data DdNode    = DdNode    deriving stock (Eq, Show)
data Agent     = Agent     deriving stock (Eq, Show)
data Prp       = Prp       deriving stock (Eq, Show)

-- I specialize this to some kind (`Type'). Otherwise the
-- kind would have to be an argument to `KnowStruct` below.
type    Dd :: Type -> Type -> Type -> Type
newtype Dd x y z = ToDd DdNode
  deriving stock (Eq, Show)

type KnowStruct :: Type
data KnowStruct = forall a b c.
  KnS DdManager [Prp] (Dd a b c) [(Agent,[Prp])]

deriving stock
  instance Show KnowStruct
```

I prefer the (equivalent) GADT syntax

```
{-# Language GADTs #-}

type KnowStruct :: Type
data KnowStruct where
  KnS :: DdManager -> [Prp] -> Dd a b c -> [(Agent,[Prp])] -> KnownStruct
```

Comment: Thank you very much for answering. Since i would like to make use of deriving Eq and the x y z are actually limited to 2 options each, should i make use of some other type declaration for Dd? If the compiler knows the phantom kinds are limited it seems to me it should be able to derive Eq, right?

Comment: It's difficult to answer without more details, but deriving `Eq` applies `(==) :: Eq a => a -> a -> Bool` to every field which requires two arguments of the exact same type. If a field has existential types like `Db` then it cannot work because you are asking for `(==) :: Db a1 b1 c1 -> Db a2 b2 c2 -> Bool`. What you can do instead is replace `Db a b c` with an existential package `data ExistsDb where Exists :: .. => Db a b c -> ExistsDb` with an `Eq ExistsDb` instance which would get picked up by `deriving` (`(==) :: ExistsDb -> ExistsDb -> Bool`). It wouldn't need standalone deriving.

Comment: i build my project with stack (ghc 8.10.7), but when i try your code i get "error:  Unsupported extension: StandaloneKindSignatures". Could not find the solution to this issue online yet. Any ideas?

Comment: According to the [user guide](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/poly_kinds.html#extension-StandaloneKindSignatures) it was intrduced in 8.10.1. It's not necessary to have a kind signature, you can omit it or write it in applicative style `newtype Dd (x :: k) (y :: j) (z :: i) = ..`